# how to display a targeted user image when clicked the user info

Tags: javascript

```js
const members = []
members[ 'frank'] = {
    firstname: 'frank',
    othername: 'princewill',
    email: 'princewill43@gmail.com',
    uniquepass: 'hhsdhhds',
    img: 'logo.jpg',
    phone: 08169543479,
},
members[ 'uzor'] = {
    firstname: 'uzor',
    othername: 'james',
    email: 'james@gmail.com',
    uniquepass: 'bhdadkdkj',
    img: 'logo.jpg',
    phone: 09876890,
};

 function getMembersUserName(){// function fot the members
    div = document.getElementById('members');
    let objKeys;
    objKeys = Object.values(members)//getting the property of the obj
    for(var i = 0; i < objKeys.length; i++){// looping the property of each member
        var liElem = document.createElement('li');
        var aElem = document.createElement('a');// link to hold the member fullname
        var loopedKeys = objKeys[i];
        var fnOn = loopedKeys.firstname.concat( ' ' + loopedKeys.othername)// full name
        aElem.innerText = fnOn;
        liElem.appendChild(aElem);
        div.appendChild(liElem);
        console.log(div)
       liElem.onclick = function(){// seting the click function
        memba_img = document.createElement('img')//create img to hold the users img
        memba_img.setAttribute('src', '')//assigning a src for the img
        var mem_phone = document.getElementById('member_phone');//id to hold the number
        var mem_img = document.getElementById('member_image');//id to hoold the img
        memba_img.src = loopedKeys.img;
        mem_img.src += (memba_img.src);
        mem_phone.innerText = loopedKeys.phone
        console.log(memba_img.src)
       // console.log()
        }

    }
    }
    getMembersUserName();
```

i'm setting up a list of members that is in array of object, each members have its own properties and the full name of the property in been loaded in another html file with appears as a link, when i click the link it should append the  image and number of the particular members which the full name it been click on but when i click the link it displays the last member image and number

this is for members profile. have tried looping the object and assigning the id that appends the image and phone value but but in console it prints the all the members image and phone contact but not showing in the innerText of the id. any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Why is members an array when you use it as an object?

Comment: That's because am running a two steps authentification for the login of members.  The keys to the object is used for one of the steps to verify if the person is a member or not

Comment: It should be an object not an array.